# Where could I find symbol _GetCurrentProcess on OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, static-linking

I'm linking nodejs as a static library to a simple c++ program on OS X 10.4 using Xcode, and I've been struggling with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GetCurrentProcess", referenced from:
      node::Platform::SetProcessTitle(char*) in libnode.a(platform_darwin_5.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone have a guess in which framework I could locate this symbol?
I read [this post](http://www.mail-archive.com/gt-user@globus.org/msg00385.html), and someone mentions this symbol is from libiodbc, but after I link with it, I still have the above error. I already link my project with CoreServices, CoreFoudations, libz and a bunch of nodeJS related libs in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be a legacy function from the days of Carbon. I don't understand any of it, but maybe if you link CarbonLib, it will fix the linker error.

http://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Carbon_Spec_Porting/Process_Manager.html

Google search phrase:
GetCurrentProcess site:developer.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

I found it in the ApplicationServices framework.  Passing `-framework ApplicationServices` to `clang` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'find' command on the command line to get a list of the library files. Then run the 'nm' command with suitable arguments on each one until you find it. You can use the '-exec' switch on 'find' to make it easier by combining these two commands.